# How good are heartbeat, elasticsearch and kibana as a monitoring/alerting solution as a replacement for Nagios?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nagios, zabbix

Since we already have filebeat, metricbeat and heartbeat configured and running.

I wonder if people have successfully implemented the ELK stack for actual monitoring with alerting/notifications instead of using traditional software as

- Nagios
- Icinga
- Zabbix

Especially since ElasticSearch now has had watchers and alerting for a while.

Comment: This is super-broad and very much opinion based. And not programming related either...

Comment: I'd say that integrating the tools is key here, each of them serves a different purpose, and does things good on its own. We had many talks on that manner at OSMC and Icinga Camp Berlin, you might want to watch them. https://osmc.de/archive-2017/videos-and-slides/ https://www.icinga.com/events/archive/2018-archive/icinga-camp-berlin/